# Unable to install the package using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-package

I am trying to install npm packages but it keeps giving me errors about network connectivity.
I have tested by changing the registry

```
// 1st 
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
2nb
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
```

but it didn't work.

**Node Version - 16.8.0**

**npm Version - 7.21.0**

[image: Error picture]

I have no idea how to solve it regardless of seeing/trying so many solutions on the internet. Please help.

Comment: does ping works ? aka ```ping https://registry.npmjs.org/```

Comment: `%2f` is a url-encoded slash, but I'm wondering why the URL in the error message uses that instead of an actual slash. The proper URL works fine: https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/preset-env So this is not really a network issue, it's an encoding issue.

Comment: Earlier it was downloading packages but from yesterday when I was trying to install @babel/core and @babel/preset-env this issue was occurring.